# mysql indexing status and running index in memory

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-like

I would like to know progress of indexing my primary column which is "URL" has around 1million rows if it is finish or still is in progress. I would like to run indexing in memory to reduce IO of hdd, more importantly I want to speed up process no more than waiting 10 minutes, because I need to delete all datas and insert new ones everyday.

Innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G

Mysql mytable structure
URL(primary)  255Varchar
filename      200Varchar

mytable 1,065,380rows   InnoDB  latin1_swedish_ci   1 GiB

```
Space usage
Data    404 MiB
Index   660 MiB
Total   1   GiB
Row Statistics
Format  dynamic
Collation   latin1_swedish_ci
Creation    Nov 18, 2017 at 02:35 PM
```

Comment: Please provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there are a couple of things we need to see.  Also, what version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM do you have?  For a 3G buffer_pool, I hope you have at least 6GB of RAM.  If not, the buffer_pool is configured so big that you are probably swapping.  This is a serious performance killer.

If you already have `PRIMARY KEY(URL)`, there is *no* reason to add `INDEX(URL)`.  The PK is already an index, and `UNIQUE`.

What query are you hoping to speed up?